# Intellij Main Class Always Changing

Tags: class, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

my question today is if there is a way for IntelliJ to build with the current class file I have Instead of always going into the configurations setting and changing the Main class from there.

Picture :
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the main class?

Comment: Not all the time would want the main class file to be Main, often times you would want to change the main class file like illustrated in the gif, so every time I would have to specify which class file is the main class file.

Comment: I don't understand it really. A java app always has just one main class. I guess you have something like small exercises which you want to run separately. If so, you just could create a `RunConfig` for each class you want to run as Main class. Then you just can choose the right run configuration from the drop down in the tool bar.

Comment: "I guess you have something like small exercises which you want to run separately." Is exactly the situation, however this statement : "create a RunConfig for each class you want to run as Main class. Then you just can choose the right run configuration from the drop down in the tool bar." Im pretty new to using intellij and don't exactly know how to do this as I am a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I now understand want you want :)

I hope this image helps.

[image]

You can create a run configuration for each class with a main method. In this example we have three classes Main1, Main2 and Main3 which you can see on the left in the image. So I created three run configurations called Main1, Main2 and Main3 which have the corresponding classes set as Main class.

You can add multiple run configurations by clicking on the green plus.

In the toolbar you then can choose the run configuration which you want to run.

EDIT:

You can just make a right click on the main method and choose the option `run`. I guess that is what you want :)

Comment: And If I were to delete the files every time per exercise, I would still have to repeat this step ?

Comment: I edited the answer. You can just make a right click in the main class and choose the option `run`.

Comment: Does that include having to create a main class configuration ?                         Correction I just checked and it does not, thank you so much!

Comment: No. You can just make a right click on the class in the tree structure or even inside the class. You don't need to create a configuration. Idea will create one.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably go in and change the default to default to that class

Comment: The problem is that I'm always creating a new main class file, so every time I have to change the main class name in the config.